# Ruby version mismatch while deploying Rails App with AWS CodeDeploy and CodePipeline Scripts on Ubuntu 20.0 EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-code-deploy, aws-code-deploy-appspec

So my Rails Application is running on Ruby2.5.7 and Rails 5.1.5. I have added appspec.yml which include multiple scripts to setup my app like

1. Setting up ENV variables
2. Installing Gems
3. Migrations
4. Assets Compile etc.

I have also installed rbenv and installed ruby 2.5.7 on instance but every time i trigger deploy the code deploy agent is using ruby 2.7 and trying to install gems on that version which is raising error `Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.5.7.` My Gemfile specifies 2.5.7 and .ruby-version is also present. I tried to switch the ruby version in myscript but nothing is working. Let me know if anyone needs more information.